# how to draw the figure in TiKz for tangential and normal component of vector at the point of curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector

how to draw the following figure in TikZ?

[image]

compile to use XeLaTeX.

I tried something already as below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[tangent/.pic={\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(2,0);}]
  
  \draw[mydarkblue,line width=1.2pt] (0,0) .. controls +(70:6) and +(-120:6) .. (5,2) coordinate[pos=0.87] (P) pic[pos=0.87,sloped,red,thick,name path=T]{tangent} pic[pos=0.87,sloped,rotate=90,blue,thick,name path=N]{tangent};


  \fill[red] (P) circle(1.3pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

BTW, merry Xmas!

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos what I tried as below: \begin{tikzpicture}[tangent/.pic={\draw[-stealth] (0,0)--(2,0);}]
  \draw[mydarkblue,line width=1.2pt] (0,0) .. controls +(70:6) and +(-120:6) .. (5,2) coordinate[pos=0.87] (P) pic[pos=0.87,sloped,red,thick,name path=T]{tangent} pic[pos=0.87,sloped,rotate=90,blue,thick,name path=N]{tangent};
  
  \fill[red] (P) circle(1.3pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: Then add that to your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OK, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can draw the rectangle at the origin and rotate the `tikzpicture`. The curly brackets are easy to draw with the `decorations` library. And the curve could be done with a couple of `arc`s, for example.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % for the curly brackets

\tikzset
{
  every node/.style={text=black},
  curly/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=3pt}},
  vector/.style={very thick,-latex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,rotate=20,scale=2,thick]
% curve and rectangle
\draw[cyan] (-1,-1) arc (180:90:1) (0,0) arc (-90:-20:2);
\draw[gray] (0,0) rectangle (1.2,1.4);
% vectors
\draw[vector,yellow!70!orange] (0,0) -- (1.2,1.4) node[above] {\bfseries a};
\draw[vector,magenta]          (0,0) -- (1,0)     node[above] {\bfseries T};
\draw[vector,green!80!blue]    (0,0) -- (0,1)     node[right] {\bfseries N};
% s, P_0
\fill[cyan] (0,0) circle (1pt);
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,-1)}]
  \draw[vector,cyan!60!black] (150:1) arc (150:120:1) node[below right] {$s$} ;
  \draw (150:1.05) -- (150:0.95) node [right] {$P_0$};
\end{scope}
% curly brackets
\draw[curly] (0,0)   -- (0,1.4) node[midway,xshift=-1.6cm] {$a_\mathrm{N}=\kappa\left(\dfrac{ds}{dt}\right)^2$};
\draw[curly] (1.2,0) -- (0,0)   node[midway,yshift=-0.8cm] {$a_\mathrm{T}=\dfrac{d^2s}{dt^2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment:  many thanks, merry christmas and happy new year

Comment: @Ben, and the same for you!!!